# How to make my login component the landing page

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to angular and I have my app running on port **4200**. I would like to add a login page which will be the default landing page when you open the web application.

My route to the login component is **/4200/login** but I want to have it as the landing page for login before you can access the application.

Any advice on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//   app-routing.module.ts
 const routes: Routes = [
      {path: '', component: LoginComponent},
      {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
    ];

//Use like this in app-routing.module.ts or Your routing module
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that does seem pretty basic. You simply have to configure your `routes` in your routing module and bind the route `''` to your login component. You can also use `redirectTo: 'login'`. Then, the login component will load when someone accesses the root route.

Comment: or you can use CanActivate in your routing file with a authentification guard service ;)